# Laravel routes, index.php and relative paths

Tags: php, web, laravel, uri, relative-path

I have a problem with Laravel and its routes, amongst other things.

I'm restructuring a website that I put online earlier this year, and I decided to use views directly instead of calling the backend data through AJAX. Since I'll be deploying to shared hosting, I moved Laravel's public folder to the project's root folder, and I moved Laravel to its own folder. I'm using WAMP for my dev environment, and currently, this is my project setup:

*project-root-folder*

- laravel

  - app
  - bootstrap
  - vendor *etc*
- css
- js
- .htaccess
- index.php *and any other files I need*

After configuring Laravel's paths in the bootstrap folder, this set up works fine, and I can navigate to *localhost/project-root-folder* to see the view that I've set up on Route::get('/').

My problem is when I try to access other pages in my website from the home page view (which I've declared using other routes to call views). Laravel keeps returning 404 error messages, and the route only works if the URL contains *localhost/project-root-folder/index.php*. I've enabled mod_rewrite on Apache in WAMP and restarted the webserver, and here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

On top of that, whenever I try to access the link to the second page using index.php in the URL (just to make sure it works), my CSS and JS files are all broken. It seems that it stops trying to find the files from the root folder, but instead tries to find them in some imaginary folder, based on the URL. So if my secondary link is called *localhost/project-root-folder/cars/all*, and in order for it to work, I have to type *localhost/project-root-folder/index.php/cars/all*, the website will try to find my CSS files in *localhost/project-root-folder/index.php/cars*, which is not what I want at all.

Here are some of the declarations of my JS and CSS files in my header layout view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./menu/css/simple_menu.css">
<script src="./js/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/translate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This links seem to work on the main page, but not any of the linked pages, even though I've specifically stated that it should check from the root folder by prepending the link with *./*.

Any help?

Comment: Why go through **all** this trouble when you can just keep the regular structure on which laravel function and have your .htaccess point to the public folder on your shared host?

Comment: if you just use laravel how it is supposed to be used by default you will avoid all of these problems as Ortix92 has stated.

Comment: @Ortix92 I was initially following a couple of websites like http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/ and https://coderwall.com/p/erbaig

I've deleted the project and restarted a new project with the original Laravel structure, and placed my code into it. I haven't touched any config files or path files, just the .htaccess, and still no luck. I feel as though I'm missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: This is what you need: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host